# Exporting afterNodeAccess from HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, java-8

In my program I have a class which extends HashMap. I'd like to execute some method after any modification made on HashMap nodes. It seems like HashMap has some interesting methods:

```
void afterNodeAccess(Node<K,V> p) { }
void afterNodeInsertion(boolean evict) { }
void afterNodeRemoval(Node<K,V> p) { }
```

But unfortunately they are all package protected and I can't override them in my class. There's of course workaround - I can move my class to `java.util` package, but it doesn't seem to me like good practice. So is there any cleaner way to achieve this?

---

Edit: I removed previous class, because it didn't make any sense. See comments under answer.

Comment: What about overriding the methods calling `afterNodeInsetion` and co?

Comment: As I said these methods are package protected. I've made HashMapModInterface class to workaround it, but I don't consider it clean enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it really a good idea to declare your class as a member of other providers package ? 
I mean not. I would do it only if I need to change the system behaviour.
If you would overwrite the 3 mentioned methods, which are callbacks for LinkedHashMap, you have no guarantee, that these methods are still existing in the next Java version

EDIT
Summary of the considerations from the comments

Use delegation instead extending Hashmap
If you implement the Map interface (without extending HashMap, only use an internal HashMap object for delegation) you will automatically get informed by the compiler if the interface is changed when you change your java version. If you extend HashMap and override protected methods, you lost this advantage. Every time, you update your Java, even with minor versions, you would have to check the sourcecode for modifications. Maybe that will cost you more amount of time than you would expect for now.

But (thanks to Holger for this advice), e.g. map.keySet().remove(x) might remove an entry from the map without calling a public modification method on the map. Similar thing with removing items using an Iterator.

So writing only a delegation of HashMap gives you not the ability to add code after every modification. But your first idea to overwrite the package protected methods is also not possible, because (Also a note of Holger) they may even disappear or change their signature within the same version of Java as they are not part of any contract. And **java.util is a prohibited package name!**

Comment: Yeah, I think so too, but there are more public methods to override than those 3. And what guarantee I have, that in next version wouldn't be more public modification methods. And those 3 protected methods are more convenient.

Comment: Thats also true. But it is only more convenient for now. If you implement the Map interface (without extending HashMap, only use an internal HashMap object for delegation) you will automatically get informed by the compiler if the interface is changed when you change your java version. If you extend HashMap and override protected methods, you lost this advantage. Every time, you update your Java, even with minor versions, you would have to check the sourcecode for modifications. Maybe that will cost you more amount of time than you would expect for now.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I'll consider this.

Comment: @Holger: I haven't written that there is a guaranty that no modification methods will added in the future. And maybe my comment above makes it more clear.

Comment: You wrote “If you overwrite the public modification methods, you have all you need, because the Map will only changed by calls of that public methods”. And that’s simply false, even without considering future changes, e.g. `map.keySet().remove(x)` might remove an entry from the map without calling a `public` modification method on the `map`. Similar thing with removing items using an `Iterator`. And burying a hint about better not using the advice within the comments doesn’t change the nature of the advice within the *answer*.

Comment: But if you like, you may notice to the questioner that the three methods he wants to override may even disappear or change their signature *within the same version* of Java as they are not part of any contract. (And I wonder how he added classes to the Java package without getting `SecurityException`s; that only works with patching the bootstrap class path, something not every JRE allows)

Comment: Ok, you are right. Iterators and sets can remove nodes without calling the public methods. Thanks for hint.

Comment: @MarPiRK: Please have a look at Holgers worth knowing comments, there is more to think about.

Comment: @Joachim: you can edit your answer to incorporate there considerations. You suggestion of using delegation is too good to be hidden within the comments.

Comment: @Holger Oh... Why Netbeans haven't reported this? Now my mistake is so obvious to me.

Comment: When you use delegation inheriting from a class *designed to be subclassed* like `AbstractMap` you have guarantees that mutations are always performed via overridable methods as documented, even if triggered by views, iterators or new `interface` `default` methods, provided that you implement `entrySet()` via a similar delegation inheriting from `AbstractSet` instead of returning an entry set of your backing map. That’s not to hard once you mastered the mind challenge that implementing a `Map` actually means implementing a `Set`…